# How to save an image created from python script including the alpha channel?

Tags: scripting, python, image

I have tried the following, and the resulting image file, when opened in GIMP, never contains an alpha channel, only R, G and B.

```
import bpy
image = bpy.data.images.new("Sprite", alpha=True, width=16, height=16)
image.filepath = "//Sprite.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()
```

Result: no alpha channel in png

```
import bpy
image = bpy.data.images.new("Sprite", alpha=True, width=16, height=16)
image.colorspace_settings.name = 'sRGB'
image.use_alpha = True
image.alpha_mode = 'STRAIGHT'
image.filepath = "//Sprite.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()
```

Result: no alpha channel in png file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in Blender, I've reported it on your behalf.

Setting `image.colorspace_settings.name` changes the alpha at the moment, [reported](https://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=36408&group_id=9&atid=498) (now fixed!)

This script works, notice it sets filepath_raw, which prevents reloading to the new path.

```
import bpy
image = bpy.data.images.new("Sprite", alpha=True, width=16, height=16)
image.use_alpha = True
image.alpha_mode = 'STRAIGHT'
image.filepath_raw = "//Sprite.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()
```

Comment: Thank you. I started to suspect that this was a bug. As a temporary solution I was temporarily set an empty layer and the render file path to do an empty render with ops.render.render(write_still=True) to produce an empty png with alpha channel and then create a temp image pointing to that file and reload. But if filepath_raw works I will do that from now on.

Comment: @ideasman42 I'm trying to use your code to save to OpenEXR. It works, but how do I specify the exr_codec when saving? My files are saving without a codec, so the file sizes are huge. I'd like to use the ZIP codec.

Comment: How to set a relative subfolder: //texture/sprites.png  doesn't work.

Comment: Prefer handle other issues as separate questions, feel free to link to them in comments here.